# What does a gradient multiplied by the inverse of the Hessian mean?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization

In the paper [VIME: Variational Information Maximizing Exploration](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.09674.pdf), the authors suggest taking a single second-order step to efficiently optimize a variant of evidence lower bound

[image]

They say

> To optimize Eq. (12) efﬁciently, we only take a single second-order step. This way, the gradient is rescaled according to the curvature of the KL divergence at the origin. As such, we compute $D_{KL} [q(\theta; \phi + \lambda\Delta\phi)\Vert q(\theta; \phi)]$, with the update step $\Delta\phi$ deﬁned as
>   $$
> \Delta\phi=H^{-1}(l)\nabla_\phi l(q(\theta;\phi),s_t) \tag{13}
> $$
>   in which $H(l)$ is the Hessian of $l(q(\theta;\phi),s_t)$.

I'm quite confused about how they obtain Eq.$(13)$: why would they multiply the gradient by the inverse of the Hessian?

Comment: This is Newton’s method!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the form of the cost function they are optimizing, but it seems to me that your question might be resolved by getting some intuition on second-order methods. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method_in_optimization) wiki entry on a fundamental example and how second derivatives (i.e. Hessians) allow us to do better optimization by using curvature information of the function.

Comment: I see, thank you so much!